# Datatable filter won't display in top left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I am currently using Datatables to apply a nice way of filtering and modifying a table that I have. It works just fine, but I am just trying to move the filter to the upper left, and the length changer to the upper right.

I have read through the [dom documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html) from the Datatables website but still cannot get it to work.

I have tried many variants of the following:

`"dom":'fltip'`

No matter how I position this, I cannot get the filter textbox to align left.

Is this something that can be done with the dom positioning attribute of the datatable, or does it have to be done in the CSS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"dom" : <'row'<'col-md-3'f>><'row'<'col-lg-12't>>
```

row is location of components, col-xx-xx is the size based on bootstrap and 'f' is for filter; 't' is for table. Feel free to play around different components.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ThisTable').DataTable({
            "bFilter": true,
            dom : "<'row'<'col-md-3'f>><'row'<'col-lg-12't>>",
```

Comment: I recommend that you don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

It loos like you need some kind of class/id with some CSS involved to get what you're looking for (based on [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/25814/using-dom-t-to-enable-tabletools-results-in-incorrectly-formatted-tables)). I'd say you're better off just running with some basic CSS.

```
<style type="text/css">
#lhs_filter {
    float: left;
}
#lhs_length {
    float: right;
}
</style>
```